# Cut the decimals in a number

Tags: javascript, truncate

I have seen some topics on truncating decimals. To be honest I do not know exactly how to do this in my example and I dont fully understand it.

```
$("#doZaplatyDollar").html((openTotal + pok1 + pok2 + pok3)/3.86513762);
```

It gives me numbers like 82.124124123 and I just need 82.12 Please help me with this one

Comment: Use `toFixed`, `((openTotal + pok1 + pok2 + pok3)/3.86513762).toFixed(2)`

Comment: @Tushar Yes, but toFixed just rounds it. It is not the exact number

Comment: You don't want to round it but trim it?

Comment: @Atul Yes, I just need to cut off the last numbers. People do it with Math.round using some additional mathematics but i totally dont get it and cant make it work

Comment: you can use parseFloat(("3.86513762").substring(0,("3.86513762").indexOf(".")+3))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to trim it, you could turn the Number into a String and use a regex to replace the last parts:

```
var val = (openTotal + pok1 + pok2 + pok3)/3.86513762;
val = val.toString().replace(/^(\d+\.\d{2}).*$/, '$1');
$("#doZaplatyDollar").html(val);
```

If you want to trim it using mathematical functions, you could do it with `Math.floor`:

```
var val = (openTotal + pok1 + pok2 + pok3)/3.86513762;
val = Math.floor(val * 100) / 100
$("#doZaplatyDollar").html(val);
```

Comment: This math floor still rounds it right? It works perfectly but the number is not exactly like on my calculator. Why :D lets say OpenTotal = $15,52 and i need few of them. There is few cents difference between the script and calculator on my table. I dont get it

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are saying? How are you doing it on your calculator? And are you getting the right result from the calculator or from the script?

Answer (score 1):

To stop rounding of toFixed you could write a method like:

```
function toFixedWithoutRound(num, precision) {
    return Math.floor(num * Math.pow(10, precision)) / Math.pow(10, precision);
}
```

Using something like that should return what you're looking for e.g.

```
// should output 82.12
toFixedWithoutRound(82.125124123, 2);
```

Hope that helps...